# How to see all tags in a git repository in command line

Tags: git, version-control

Is there something like "git show tags"?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`git tag` to list tags used in the repo.

`git tag -l` if you use the `-l` option you can pass a search pattern to filter out tags.

Comment: Thanks (also to @VonC), I also found that "git describe --tags" will show the last used tag.

Comment: To see details about the latest available tag I sometimes use:

$ git show `git describe` --pretty=fuller

Answer (score 10):

```
git tag -l
git tag

-l <pattern>
```

> List tags with names that match the given pattern (or all if no pattern is given).
>   Typing "**`git tag`**" without arguments, also lists all tags

See also [GitHub tagging](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html).
And I mentioned in "[How to sort git tags by version string order of form rc-X.Y.Z.W?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309)" to sort order used for listing tags.

Comment: Note that `<pattern>` doesn't support composer versions like tilde `~`

Comment: @PauAI I agree: looking at the composer doc, I see the tilde operator (http://qpleple.com/understand-composer-versions/) referencing the "Next Significant Release". There is indeed no such thing, mainly because Git tags don't follow semantic versioning and are free-formed strings.

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
git ls-remote --tags YOUR_REPOSITORY_NAME
```