# How to sort git tags by version string order of form rc-X.Y.Z.W?

Tags: git, sorting, tags

When I enter a command:

```
git tag -l
```

I get such results:

```
rc-0.9.0.0
rc-0.9.0.1
rc-0.9.0.10
rc-0.9.0.11
rc-0.9.0.12
rc-0.9.0.2
rc-0.9.0.3
rc-0.9.0.4
rc-0.9.0.5
rc-0.9.0.6
rc-0.9.0.7
rc-0.9.0.8
rc-0.9.0.9
```

Instead of this I want:

```
rc-0.9.0.0
rc-0.9.0.1
rc-0.9.0.2
rc-0.9.0.3
rc-0.9.0.4
rc-0.9.0.5
rc-0.9.0.6
rc-0.9.0.7
rc-0.9.0.8
rc-0.9.0.9
rc-0.9.0.10
rc-0.9.0.11
rc-0.9.0.12
```

How it's possible to sort current list to get such results?

Comment: With Git 2.0, you will soon be able to do a `git tag -l --sort=version:refname "rc-*"`, and get the output you want. see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309)

Comment: Git 2.0 is out now, and all the answers below using 'sort' are no longer needed. [`--sort` is available for git tag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Use version sort

```
git tag -l | sort -V
```

or for git version >= 2.0

```
git tag -l --sort=v:refname
git tag -l --sort=-v:refname # reverse
```

Comment: @miku please check! for me it does

Comment: The -V argument isn't available on the OS X(10.8)-provided version (5.93) of sort. :(

Comment: you can use homebrew or macports to install the gnu version of sort.
`brew install gsort` then you can modify the line above to `git tag -l | gsort -V` and it should work for you.

Comment: I had to use `brew install coreutils` to get the `gsort` command. `brew install gsort` failed, saying there was no package called `gsort`.

Comment: No luck on msysgit either

Comment: Now works with Git for Windows 2.0 (official replacement for msysGit, https://git-for-windows.github.io/), since it has updated GNU coreutils.

Comment: debian based `sort` reverse sort option is `-r`, not -V

Comment: @ssoto right, but  it's about natural sorting of version numbers - not reverse sorting.

Comment: `sort -Vf` comes in really handy when you need case-insensitive. I know a big project tree that has `beta` and `RC` capitalization messed up in their tags. This causes `RC` to show up before `beta`.

Comment: to get last five tags with desc sort ```git tag --sort=-v:refname | head -5```

Comment: also, no pager `git --no-pager tag -l --sort=v:refname`

Answer (score 121):

With Git 2.0 (June 2014), you will be able to specify a sorting order!

See [commit b6de0c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6de0c633e60424d8d7e31a6557854683f2e4e43), from [commit 9ef176b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ef176b55c373ba087b2d84e77b5713578891927), authored by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

```
 --sort=<type>
```

> **Sort in a specific order**.
>   Supported type is:
>
> - "`refname`" (lexicographic order),
> - "`version:refname`" or "`v:refname`" (tag names are treated as versions).
>
> Prepend "`-`" to reverse sort order.

---

So, if you have:

```
git tag foo1.3 &&
git tag foo1.6 &&
git tag foo1.10
```

Here is what you would get:

```
# lexical sort
git tag -l --sort=refname "foo*"
foo1.10
foo1.3
foo1.6

# version sort
git tag -l --sort=version:refname "foo*"
foo1.3
foo1.6
foo1.10

# reverse version sort
git tag -l --sort=-version:refname "foo*"
foo1.10
foo1.6
foo1.3

# reverse lexical sort
git tag -l --sort=-refname "foo*"
foo1.6
foo1.3
foo1.10
```

---

Since [commit b150794](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b150794dafb0a7a1c5caba6fdf7d517a1a15cb59) (by Jacob Keller, git 2.1.0, August 2014), you can specific that default order:

```
tag.sort
```

> This variable controls the sort ordering of tags when displayed by [`git-tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag).
>   Without the "`--sort=<value>`" option provided, the value of this variable will be used as the default.

[robinst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305973/robinst) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273531/how-to-sort-git-tags/22634649?noredirect=1#comment39746402_22634649):

> the version sort order can now (Git 2.1+) be configured as default:

```
git config --global tag.sort version:refname
```

As noted by [Leo Galleguillos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3195596/leo-galleguillos) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273531/how-to-sort-git-tags-by-version-string-order-of-form-rc-x-y-z-w/22634649#comment109673763_22634649):

> To configure Git to show **newest tags first** (**descending** order), just add a **hyphen before version**.
>   The command becomes:
>
> ```
> git config --global tag.sort -version:refname
> ```

---

With [Git 2.4 (Q2 2015)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e80e85a52adfda053cafc3b23058a86aff35404f#diff-2dda503b6844ed42259098aa1d9db348R100), **the `versionsort.prerelease` configuration variable can be used to specify that `v1.0-pre1` comes before `v1.0`**.

See [commit f57610a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f57610a1ff7a547d1e11e24f942b1703cea81f81) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).

<sup>Note (see below) `versionsort.prereleaseSuffix` is now (2017) a deprecated alias for `versionsort.suffix`.</sup>

---

git 2.7.1 (February 2016) will improve the output of `git tag` itself.

See [commit 0571979](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0571979bd60837d3c0802ecc1a47c48b4a6114d0) (26 Jan 2016), and [commit 1d094db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d094db936331abc42d859269181272a8539c7ae) (24 Jan 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8bad3de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bad3de2c8390d952308652493fb72f58820895e), 01 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ## `tag`: do not show ambiguous tag names as "`tags/foo`"
>
> Since [b7cc53e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7cc53e92c806b73e14b03f60c17b7c29e52b4a4) (`tag.c`: use '`ref-filter`' APIs, 2015-07-11), `git tag` has started showing tags with ambiguous names (i.e., when both "`heads/foo`" and "`tags/foo`" exists) as "`tags/foo`" instead of just "`foo`".
>   This is both:
>
> - pointless; the output of "`git tag`" includes only `refs/tags`, so we know that "`foo`" means the one in "`refs/tags`".
> - and ambiguous; in the original output, we know that the line "`foo`" means that "`refs/tags/foo`" exists. In the new output, it is unclear whether we mean "`refs/tags/foo`" or "`refs/tags/tags/foo`".
>
> The reason this happens is that commit b7cc53e switched `git tag` to use ref-filter's "`%(refname:short)`" output formatting, which was adapted from `for-each-ref`. This more general code does not know that we care only about tags, and uses `shorten_unambiguous_ref` to get the `short-name`.
>   We need to tell it that we care only about "`refs/tags/`", and it should shorten with respect to that value.
>
> let's add a new modifier to the formatting language, "**`strip`**", to remove a specific set of prefix components.
>   This fixes "`git tag`", and lets users invoke the same behavior from their own custom formats (for "`tag`" or "`for-each-ref`") while leaving "`:short`" with its same consistent meaning in all places.
>
> If `strip=<N>` is appended, strips `<N>` slash-separated path components from the front of the refname (e.g., `%(refname:strip=2)` turns `refs/tags/foo` into `foo`.
>   `<N>` must be a positive integer.
>   If a displayed ref has fewer components than `<N>`, the command aborts with an error.

For `git tag`, when unspecified, defaults to `%(refname:strip=2)`.

---

Update Git 2.12 (Q1 2017)

See [commit c026557](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c026557a37361b7019acca28f240a19f546739e9), [commit b178464](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b17846432da4f8530c7349561eac4a16f95bbd5b), [commit 51acfa9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51acfa9db588ddd8c3aff2acbc1a85ae7ac239f6), [commit b823166](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8231660fa95f6e9e07b9e2483e254c2de045275), [commit 109064a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/109064a0313c8a7c337f37936077ef3c9171d7ce), [commit 0c1b487](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c1b4878dec423a0d322bffc5607de584aab214e), [commit 9ffda48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ffda48f53e086895975f2a435afff01c836dad2), [commit eba286e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eba286e31012335370aedb7572ff51df549eb3f3) (08 Dec 2016) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1ac244d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac244d5b20a9ea4a640e2ee80b9818f564aa237), 23 Jan 2017)</sup>

`versionsort.prereleaseSuffix` is a deprecated alias for `versionsort.suffix`.

> The `prereleaseSuffix` feature of version comparison that is used in
>   "`git tag -l`" did not correctly when two or more prereleases for the
>   same release were present (e.g. when `2.0`, `2.0-beta1`, and `2.0-beta2`
>   are there and the code needs to compare `2.0-beta1` and `2.0-beta2`).

Comment: `--sort` doesn't exist on git 1.9.1. (worked on 2.0.0)

Comment: @TeaBee true, I have edited the answer accordingly, since Git 2.0 is released now.

Comment: With Git 2.1.0, the version sort order can now be configured as default: `git config --global tag.sort version:refname`

Comment: @robinst Good point, thank you. I have included it in the answer, with a link to the git commit which introduced that feature.

Comment: It would be worth explaining why this is better than `sort -V`. The only advantage I see is portability to systems that don't have GNU sort. But if you have it `| sort -V` golfs better. The thing is: this sort method does not use any Git-specific information (unlike e.g. topological order of object pointed to as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900328/git-command-to-show-all-lightweight-tags-creation-dates)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功 I agree. I prefer the `git tag --sort` method though.

Comment: Interestingly, it understands both `customtext-1.1.0` and `1.1.0-customtext`. Sorts both flawlessly, assuming you just choose one format. Not really sure if it will work if you mix it, though I think it as a bad idea ;)

Comment: `git tag --sort=-taggerdate` to get the recently tag

Comment: To configure git to show newest tags first (descending order), just add a hyphen before `version`. The command becomes: `git config --global tag.sort -version:refname`

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 21):

Combining the answers already here:

### Local repository

```
git -c 'versionsort.suffix=-' tag --list --sort=-v:refname
```

- `suffix=-` will prevent `2.0-rc` coming "after" `2.0`
- `--sort=-` will put the highest version number at the top.

### Remote repository

```
git -c 'versionsort.suffix=-' ls-remote -t --exit-code --refs --sort=-v:refname "$repo_url" \
    | sed -E 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:space:]]+refs\/tags\/(.+)/\1/g'
```

The advantage of this is that no objects are downloaded from the remote.

For more info see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52661928/5353461).

Comment: Very interesting use of `versionsort.suffix`. +1.

Comment: `ls-remote --sort` is not supported in **Git < 2.0**. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390720/658497 how to workaround.

Comment: Can you hard code `--sort=-v:refname` as a default in your local config somehow?

Answer (score 12):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091360/245945), on platforms which don't support `sort -V` like Windows and OSX, you can use

`git tag -l | sort -n -t. -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4`

Comment: @Ovi-WanKenobi you need to run it on Cygwin (or mingw) shell.

Answer (score 2):

To get a reverse sorting with the `sort -V` approach:

```
git tag -l | sort -V --reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapt [this perl script](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/VersionPathSorter), which sorts tags that look like `client_release/7.2/7.2.25`, to your specific tagging scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a simple shell script to simplify this task.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TAGS=$(git tag)
CODE=$?

if [ $CODE = 0 ]; then
    echo "$TAGS" | sort -V
fi

exit $CODE
```

I saved that as `git-tags` in my `$PATH` and run `git tags` whenever I need to list tags.

Comment: git tag | sort -V ; exit $PIPESTATUS

Answer (score 1):

**If you're on Linux and using ZSH**; Simply use `gtl` command. It should be predefined as an Alias for you.

> Alias code:
> `gtl='gtl(){ git tag --sort=-v:refname -n -l "${1}*" }; noglob gtl'`

Answer (score -1):

try list for special formate with last one

`git tag -l --sort=refname | grep -E '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*' | tail -n 1`

or first one

`git tag -l --sort=refname | grep -E '^\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*' | head -n 1`