# How to determine latest production release from a git master branch?

Tags: git

I am still a newbie on git. When I did a *git clone ...* on any packages, it mostly downloads from the master branch.

My understanding is a master branch should contain both development and release codes.
If so, is it possible to find out the latest (production) release version from the downloaded master branch?

Answer (score 3):

If every release is marked with an **annotated** tag, [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is what you need (cite from man page):

> git-describe - Show the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit

If your last released version is for example `2.6.9`, `git describe` will give you the following output:

```
2.6.9-<NUMCOMMITS>-g<CURRENTREV>
```

If your current branch points directly to `2.6.9`, `NUMCOMMITS` and `CURRENTREV` will not be printed and the command only yields `2.6.9`.

However, if you did some commits since `2.6.9` (e.g. 3), `NUMCOMMITS` will be `3` and `CURRENTREV` will be the 7 chars of the abbreviated last commit hash (e.g. `2597536`):

```
2.6.9-3-g2597536
```

Same could be achieved for unannotated tags using the `--tags` switch:

```
git describe --tags
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP precises [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833383/how-to-determine-latest-production-release-from-a-git-master-branch/26833392?noredirect=1#comment42238993_26833392) that "release version" isn't about having binaries (deliveries) in the repo, but getting the versions which are used to produced delivery.

[`git tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) alone is not well suite, because the order isn't always pertinent.

However, as i explained in "[How to sort git tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309)", this would give the right order (with git 2.0+)

```
git tag -l --sort=refname "v*"
# or
git tag -l --sort=version:refname "v*"

v17
v16
...
v9
...
v1
```

Comment: I would only add that it's project-specific, and while it seems his project isn't using the ["successful git branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) that some number of projects use, there might very well be some branch that has all the release-tagged commits in its first-parent history.

Comment: @jthill I agree: Git itself doesn't impose anything. This is more about the convention and worflow you want to follow for your project.

Comment: Perhaps, I asked a wrong question. To illustrate, I will use kmod.git package [link](git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kmod/kmod.git). After cloning the repo, I did a *git tag* and it dumps tag list (**v1 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9**). What I would like to do is to be able to grab the latest tag, i.e. v17, from the list. This way, I can write a Makefile recipe to clone or checkout the package source based on the latest tag. I hope that clears up some misunderstanding.

Comment: @user3767809 ok, I have entirely rewritten the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, your suggestion requires a git v2.0+. This may create some problem because not everyone is currently using git v2.0+, unfortunately.  OTOH, you also mentioned about 'git tag'. When I took a look at 'git tag', I can use 'sort + tail' utilities to perform a sort and get the latest version as I want, i.e. *git tag -l | sort --sort=version | tail -1*. However, I don't know if this is the correct way.

Comment: @user3767809 I agree but updating git is easy, so this shouldn't be an issue (unless you are using Git on Windows, in which case, this is problematic) Your sort+tail version could then work just fine.

Comment: Yes and that will do with additional gnu utilities, i.e. git tag | sort -V + tail -1.