# Get last git tag matching string

Tags: git, tagging

In git, let's say I have multiple tags with revision numbers, something like:

```
v1.1.0
v1.2.0
v1.2.1
v1.2.3
```

I'm interested in getting the last version number from the tag.  If I do

`git describe --tags --match "v1.2.*"`

I will get `v1.2.0` as the result, but I really want `v1.2.3`

Comment: `git describe` is used to find a tag that is reachable from HEAD.  It sounds more like you just want to list out the tags and then sort them perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all tags, using a specifc order, you can (with git 2.0+) use a sort option.
See "[How to sort git tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309)"

```
git tag -l --sort=refname "v1.2.*"
# or (note the '-' sign in '-version' to reverse the order)
git tag -l --sort=-version:refname "v1.2.*"
```

In each case, the *first* result should be  v1.2.3

Comment: I want just one tag, and git 2.0 isn't officially supported on Windows yet, which is the platform I need this for

Comment: @Alex to get one tag, you can use `head` (from https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow). But using on windows is indeed an issue (no Git2.x released yet in the new http://git-for-windows.github.io/ that I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309, although it's coming soon: http://osdir.com/ml/msysgit/2014-11/msg00015.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with **git describe**:

```
git describe --tags --match "v1.2.*" $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
```

Helped this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811684/3598880