# How to group output in command shell

Tags: git, shell

when I run `git tag` command in linux terminal I get output as

```
bssg-v1.0-alpha.0.1
bssg-v1.0-alpha.0.2
bssg-v1.0-alpha.0.3
bssg-v1.0-alpha.0.4
dummy
opal-0.5
opal-0.6
pisn_final
pisn_v1.2
pisn_v1.2.1
pisn_v1.2.2
pisn_v1.3
pisn_v1.3.1
pisn_v1.3.2
pisn_v1.3.3
pisn_v1.3.4
ralp_0.1
ralp_0.2
ralp_0.3
ralp_0.4
ralp_0.4.1
ralp_0.4.2
salp-v0.1-alpha.0.1
salp-v0.1-alpha.0.2
salp-v0.1-alpha.0.3
salp-v0.1-alpha.0.4
tms-1a-0.3
tms-1a-0.4
```

What i want is this kind of output...

```
bssg
dummy
opal
pisn
ralp
salp
tms
```

i.e on running `git tag` I should get only characters before any '-' or '_' and that too only once.
How can I do this.. ???

Answer (score 3):

[`git tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) itself doesn't seem to have that filtering capability.
(even though [its sort ordering did improve recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309))

But a shell does (even on Windows, with the one packaged with [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/))

```
git tag|sed "s/\([^-_]*\)[-_].*/\1/g"|sort|uniq
```