# Get only tags / references of a git remote repository

Tags: git, git-fetch

Is it possible to get the tags / references of a repository (eg GitHub) without downloading objects / files?

My use case is in packaging the latest beta release of some software which has a long history and is therefore large to clone.

Ideally after I determine the tag that I wish to use, I can then:

```
git clone -b "$tag" --depth=1
```

Comment: Refer https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote

Answer (score 6):

Use [`git ls-remote`](https://manned.org/git-ls-remote.1):

```
$ git ls-remote -t --refs <URL>
```

This gives output such as:

```
8f235769a2853c415f811b19cd5effc47cc89433        refs/tags/continuous
24e666ed73486a2ac65f09a1479e91e6ae4a1bbe        refs/tags/continuous-develop
7c2cff2c26c1c2ad4b4023a975cd2365751ec97d        refs/tags/v2.0
35b69eed46e5b163927c78497983355ff6a5dc6b        refs/tags/v2.0-beta10
```

You probably also want to pass `--exit-code` to ensure a non-`0` exit when no matching refs are returned.

To get only the tag names, pass through:

`sed -E 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:space:]]+refs\/tags\/(.+)/\1/g'`:

```
$ git ls-remote -t --exit-code --refs https://github.com/robert7/nixnote2.git \
  | sed -E 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:space:]]+refs\/tags\/(.+)/\1/g'
continuous
continuous-develop
v2.0
v2.0-beta10
```

Suggestions:

- Pass `--exit-code` to ensure a non-`0` exit when no matching refs are returned.
- Use the `https://` version: it's faster and if you're packaging you don't want to run the risk of being asked for a ssh key.
- `--sort=-v:refname` to sort by version rather than lexographically, and have the largest versions at the top
- Use `git -c versionsort.suffix=-` to prevent `2.0-rc` coming "after" `2.0`
- Add a pattern at the end of the command line to filter. Eg `'v*'` if all version tags start with a `v`.