# Git Command To Find Previous Branch of Specific Type

Tags: git

We are using gitflow within my organization, particularly the concept of release branches. We also support multiple simultaneous release branches. A sample repo may look like so:

```
master -> a
           \
            \    c <-release/v1.0.0    e <-release/v1.1.0    g <-release/v1.2.0
             \  /                     /                     /
    develop-> b ---------------------d---------------------f
```

What I'd like to do is given a currently checked out release branch, find the predecessor release branch. For example:

```
-release/v1.2.0 is checked out, return release/v1.1.0
-release/v1.1.0 is checked out, return release/v1.0.0
-release/v1.0.0 is checked out, return nothing, there is no currently active previous release
```

We are using this to determine what files have changed between releases for deployment to a legacy system.

Assumptions: Release branches will always follow the format `release/v.x.y.z`, where x,y and z are version numbers. Release branches are always organized sequentially based on these version numbers. `v1.2.1 > v1.2.0` and `v1.2.0 > 1.1.0`

I considered using some combination of `git branch --list -a *release/v*` to get a list of all release branches and some perl commands to sort through the results, but was wondering if there was some git commands along the vein of `git rev-parse` or `git rev-list` that could do it.

Notes: I am using z/OS USS ports of unix tools, git, bash, grep etc.

Comment: "Notes: I am using z/OS USS ports of unix tools, git, bash, grep etc.": I see...: https://forum.rocketsoftware.com/tags/git, https://forum.rocketsoftware.com/t/using-git-for-z-os-with-github/654: https://forum.rocketsoftware.com/t/git-2-14-4-for-z-os-is-now-available/1217. I suppose you are on Git 2.14.4

Comment: Yes, we are in the process of upgrading our git version to 2.14.4. I tried out your command below and it does work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if (with the latest Git 2.21) the [sort order for tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309) can be used for branches:

```
git branch --sort=version:refname
```

That way, you can get the right order before git grepping.

The [OP patrickw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9829658/patrickw) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960686/git-command-to-find-previous-branch-of-specific-type/55963389#comment100888486_55963389) using:

```
git branch --list -r *release/v* --sort=-version:refname
```

Comment: I ultimately used a modified version of this command along with some bash to get the job done, thanks!

`git branch --list -r *release/v* --sort=-version:refname`

Comment: @patrickw Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

There is no git-specific command, but you don't need to involve Perl, standard bash sort should do the work:

```
git branch --list -a *release/v* | sort -V | grep -B1 <current_version> | head -1
```

(note the -V option ->[man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html))

Also note that you can't even get the name of the current branch without some text processing. See answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git).

Comment: I can get the current branch using a `git rev-parse`, no problem. Using the above example, my version of grep on uss does not recognize 1 as an option and I get nothing back to stdout. Am I supposed to redirect the output of this command to a file?

Comment: "1" is a parameter to -B option that makes grep display that many lines of context before the match (->[man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)). If your grep doesn't support it, well, google for alternatives...

Comment: I have this severely IBM hampered version of grep installed on the system that does not recognize context lines, and I don't see any alternative commands that do. I don't think the above would work in this case.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/grep.htm