# How can I get my GIT tags in the order that they were created?

Tags: git, versioning, setuptools, setup.py, git-tag

I am facing an issue where I am using git (version 2.27.0.windows.1) and want to sort so that I am able to use the most recent one. Right now got the following list of tags:

```
abc_a_r0.1.1   
abc_b_r0.1.2   
abc_c_r1.2.3   
abc_d_r1.2.4   
abc_r5.4.9    
abc_r6.0.0    
abc_r6.0.1    
abc_r6.0.10    
abc_r6.0.11    
abc_r6.0.13    
abc_r6.0.14    
abc_r6.0.15    
abc_r6.0.16    
abc_r6.0.2    
abc_r6.0.3    
abc_r6.0.4    
abc_r6.0.5    
abc_r6.0.6    
abc_r6.0.7    
abc_r6.0.8    
abc_r6.0.9
```

if I use the command `git describe --tags --match "abc_r*" --abbrev=0` I'm getting `abc_r6.0.9` as the output whereas I'm looking to get the latest tag which is abc_r6.0.16. This is becoming challenging as my setup.py looks something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools_scm import get_version

def get_requirements():
    with open('requirements.txt') as fd:
        return [req for req in fd.read().splitlines() if req[0].isalpha()]


setup(use_scm_version={'version_scheme': 'guess-next-dev', 'git_describe_command': 'git describe --match "abc_r*"',                           
      install_requires=get_requirements(),)
```

And I'm using the tag to version our python package.
Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: To show the necessary information about the  candidates, do `git log --graph --decorate-refs=refs/tags/abc_r6*  --oneline --simplify-by-decoration` and `git show -s --pretty=fuller abc_r6.0.9` and `git show -s --pretty=fuller abc_r6.0.16`,  and post the results.

Answer (score 5):

Check fist if the [`--sort` option of `git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---sortltkeygt) can help.

I mentioned [`taggerdate` before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919313/6309)

```
git tag --sort=taggerdate
```

That would display tags from oldest to most recent.

Alternatively:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(taggerdate): %(refname)" --sort=-taggerdate refs/tags
# or
git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format '%(tag)'
```

With:

- `--sort=creatordate` works for [both annotated and unannotated tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919313/6309).
- `--sort=taggerdate` for annotated tags.

Answer (score 0):

As @VonC suggested : `git tag` has a `--sort` option.

This option has a special value `version:refname` (or `v:refname`) to search for version numbers in tag names :

```
git tag --sort=v:refname

# add '-' if you want them in descending order (biggest version first) :
git tag --sort=-v:refname
```

Comment: Yes, I have documented `v:refname` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634649/6309. But if you want the latest, as in most recently created, I would prefer `--sort=taggerdate`, in order to not rely on a naming convention which may not always be strictly followed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to sort your tags by `creatordate`:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname) %(creatordate)' refs/tags
```

Comment: This seems identical to what VonC wrote an hour previously?