# Git branch not in alphabetical order

Tags: git, terminal

I'm setting up a new machine as a development environment. When I type `git branch` the branches arn't in alphabetical order, which I've never seen before.

What are the possible causes of this? I know I havn't provided much information but I'm not sure how to start debugging this.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the non-alphabetically sorted output you get?

Comment: Im afraid I cant share this for security reasons. Might sound paranoid but my work is very strict.

Comment: You may want to check the configuration file stored in the repo if there is one: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: There are some details here that might help you to resort when using the branch command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273531/how-to-sort-git-tags-by-version-string-order-of-form-rc-x-y-z-w.

Comment: Two different machines are outputting `git branch` order differently? Are those two machines the same OS? Is the difference related to upper vs lowercase letters?

Comment: Are there slashes in your branch names?

Comment: Note: the linked question is about sorting tags, but you can sort branch names the same way, as branch names, tag names, and all other names in Git use a single common underlying mechanism.

Comment: The default sort order is "alphabetical as determined by the locale" (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75341/162084)), so it's possible you have different collation orders on the two systems.

Comment: @Alex028502 yes some names start with _