# Browse list of tagged releases in a repo?

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout OpenSSL 1.0.2a (and not Master). OpenSSL has tagged releases, and I'm trying to browse them to determine what the actual name is. I know they have 1.0.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 (but they are named more complexly).

According to [OpenSSL Git repository](https://www.openssl.org/source/repos.html), the repo is located at git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git.

According to [How to see all tags in a git repository in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3231079/608639), I need to use `git tag`:

```
$ git tag git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How do I browse the tagged releases held in a Git repo?

---

For completeness, [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911) does not discuss this topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`git tag` assumes you have a clone of the repo checked out locally. (Which is why it complains about not being in a git repository.)

To achieve what you desire, you probably want to first clone it, then switch to the desired tag:

```
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
cd openssl
git tag -l                   # to list the tags
git checkout tags/<name>     # to switch to the desired tag
```

You can also get a list of the tags in the remote repository without doing a `git clone` first, by using the following command:

```
git ls-remote --tags git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I was not aware there was a distinction like that.

Comment: *"You probably want to first clone it, then switch to the desired tag"* - actually, its the other way around. Once I determine the branch I want, I will checkout the branch and not Master. Master is much different in the particular area I want to make the changes.

Comment: @jww `clone` and `checkout` are two different things. While it is possible to clone a repository and fetch only a specific subset of all branches, it's much easier to just clone the entire repository and checkout whichever branch you are interested in.

Comment: `git tags` doesn't work for me. Should it be `git tag`?